# Haskell Aeson JSON Library ByteString Issue

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm having trouble finding a function or workaround to convert a **String** to `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString`

One of the functions in the Aeson Json library is `decode` and has the following description:

```
decode :: FromJSON a => bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString -> Maybe a
```

I've tried using the pack function in Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 but that returns a different ByteString. Any one know how this can be fixed?

The following is the example I'm working on:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad (mzero)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal as BLI
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BSL

data Person = Person 
    { name :: Text
    , age :: Int 
    } deriving Show

instance FromJSON Person where 
    parseJSON (Object v) = Person <$>
                   v .: (pack "name") <*>
                   v .: (pack "age")
    parseJSON _          = mzero
```

I tried using `decode (BSL.pack "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}") :: Maybe Person`
and got the following error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
                with actual type `BSL.ByteString'
    In the return type of a call of `BSL.pack'
    In the first argument of `decode', namely
      `(BSL.pack "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}")'
    In the expression:
        decode (BSL.pack "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}") :: Maybe Person
```

Help!

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of bytestring installed? Try running `ghc-pkg list bytestring` to check.

Comment: The list comes up with two items bytestring-0.10.0.2 and bytestring-.10.4.0 - will this cause an issue? I know I had a GHCI linking error earlier when I was playing around with the code above.

Comment: Yes, I had to unregister bytestring-10.4.0 to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert Char to Word8 using c2w (in Data.ByteString.Internal)

```
Data.ByteString.Lazy.pack $ map c2w "abcd"
```

I wrote out the fully qualified name for pack also to guarantee using the correct one, but you can clean this up in the imports section.  When I run

```
> :t Data.ByteString.Lazy.pack $ map c2w "abcd"
```

I get ":: Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString"

Remember that Data.ByteString.Lazy represents strings of number values (you can't even run its pack on strings, you need to supply an array of numbers "pack [1, 2, 3, 4]"), so you might actually want to use the char equivalent Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.

Comment: I managed to get the correct type using this. So I am getting Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString but now its asking for byteString-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString. Hmm I think this might be an issue bennofs commented on the original post because I have two versions of bytestrings?

Comment: There very well might be a version problem, but remember that even within a single version of the libraries, there are four bytestrings- strict/Word8, strict/Char8, lazy/Word8 and strict/Char8....  and pack will only directly work on a string for the Char8 versions.

Comment: Brilliant had another issue with two bytestrings being installed which has also been fixed as mentioned in the comment in the original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use for convenience `fromString` from `Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8` from [utf8-string](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string).

It's a module of functions for the same ByteString type as aeson uses. It relyies on UTF8 as the encoding used in the buffers.